# use regex to specify output filename

Tags: regex, shell, sh

I have a folder with many files where I only need some columns so I tried this to extract what I need:

```
mkdir ./raw_data/selection

doit() {
    csvfix read_dsv -f 1,3,7 -s \; $1 > $1 | sed 's/raw_data/raw_data\/selection/'
}
export -f doit
Files_To_Parse=`ls ./raw_data/*csv`
parallel doit ::: $Files_To_Parse
```

This doesn't work.

But if I to this:

```
cd ./raw_data
doit() {
    csvfix read_dsv -f 1,3,7 -s \; $1 > selection/$1
}
export -f doit
Files_To_Parse=`ls -1 *csv`
parallel doit ::: $Files_To_Parse
```

it works but I'd like to be able to run this from the top folder in this project (i.e to put this in a file named `brief_csv.sh` and call it from IDEs)

Comment: Is that a typo that you don't have the "-1" option in the ls command in your first attempt? I would expect that to be necessary. For you main problem, if this is Bash, have you tried "$1 > ./raw_data/selection/${1:9}"? Otherwise, maybe "$1 > $(echo $1 | sed 's/raw_data/raw_data\/selection/')"?

Comment: `ls` knows when it's writing to a pipe, and automatically enables `-1` behavior. The option is only really necessary when you want to see what the output looks like in an inteactive session.

Comment: Anyway, don't use `ls` in scrips. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs The proper way to do this is simply `parallel doit ::: *csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used Bash, you could:

```
for f in raw_data/*.csv
do 
    csvfix ... "$f" > raw_data/selection/"${f##*/}"
done
```

Also, instead of `csvfix` for extracting columns you could use `cut`:

```
$ cut -d \; -f 1,3,7 $f ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the commands you are using, but this line:

> csvfix read_dsv -f 1,3,7 -s \; $1 > $1 | sed ...

redirects the output in the same file you are reading; this can not work. In fact, you say that your modified code instead works. You could use temporary files to store intermediate results, don't be afraid to use many of them: debugging will be easier (you can see intermediate passages) and the system doesn't suffer. /tmp is a good place to put those intermediate files.

Use csvfix to do the first step, and redirect in /tmp/my-csvfix-intermediate; then use sed to read /tmp/my-csvfix-intermediate, and write in /tmp/my-grep-intermediate. After the last passage, you can take the last intermediate result and overwrite the original file, perhaps after having backed it up. You can move files everywhere you need, I don't see any problem in running your script from an IDE - just use as many passages as you need.

Avoid to parallelize when debugging, when the script will work, you can add parallelizing.

When two or more parallel processes will try to write in the same file (/tmp/my-...-intermediate), you will have one more problem. To overcome this you need to use different files for every process. The bash variable "$$" comes to help, just use file names like "/tmp/my-$$-blablabla", the $$ will be substituted with the PID of the process, and parallel processes can not have the same PID.

Hope it helps, regards.